# Skrollr.js simple parallaxed bg images

Tags: jquery, skrollr

I am using skrollr.js to create a simple parallax effect on background images. I have three 100% width and height sections. Then I am moving the bg position of the first for the duration of 500 scrolled pixels. The problem is that I get unwanted whitespace when doing it, I believe that it is there due to changing the bg position.

Here is the [link](http://www.madebym.me/test/Poligate/) to example in question.
Here is the code for this effect:

```
 data-0="background-position:0px 0px;" data-500="background-position:0px -100px;"
```

Comment: What do you expect instead of the whitespace? The image is simply not large enough.

Comment: But I see it also on a 15' laptop, the image is 1920x1080. Is it maybe because of cover property?

Comment: Sure, because it will be exactly the height/width of the container...

Comment: Really sorry to hassle you with trivial stuff, but what is your advice in this situation?

Comment: Use a child element which is (in this case) 100px higher and put the background-image on this instead. Let the child element overflow the parent. Now you got 100px to spare.

Comment: I know what you said is pure logic but... sometimes you just need to hear it to get it! Thank you Prinzhorn for this comment and the Skrollr itself. Great piece of code!

Comment: Man it's frustrating to see a question that is similar to my own but the link to the "example" doesn't exist anymore.